UIStackView conflict strangely with Top Align in Alignment axis?
I have two top aligned HStackViews(with red & green background color) embeded in a VStackView.
If I add a label to each HStackView , the layout will got a vertical conflict like this:


And if I add one more label to any HStackView , the conflict will be disappear.(set the horizontal content priority with differenct value on each label)

I have two questions here:

I think the UIStackView have intrinsic vertical size as it's biggest
subview. the conflict should not happen .
as the conflict generated
as above. Why the conflict will disappear after I adding one more
label to it ?


You get the "Missing Y Constraints" error / warning because your layout is ambiguous.
You've added a Vertical stack view and told auto-layout to arrange its subviews based on their content.
The 1st subview - the Red Horizontal stack view - has a single label with the default Vertical Content Hugging Priority: 251
The 2nd subview - the Green Horizontal stack view - also has a single label with the default Vertical Content Hugging Priority: 251
So the Vertical stack view says: "Hmmm... the designer has not told me how to distribute the two Horizontal stack view, so I'll allow the 1st (Top) stack view to stretch vertically."
That behavior is actually undefined... it may or may not actually lay out that way.
When you add a second label to either Horizontal stack view (let's use the Green one since that's the image you posted), the Vertical stack view says: "OK ... the designer has TWO subviews with Vertical Content Hugging Priority: 251 in the bottom arranged subview, and only ONE subview with Vertical Content Hugging Priority: 251 in the top arranged subview... so I'll allow the 1st (Top) stack view to stretch vertically."
If you instead added a second label to the Red Horizontal stack view, the Vertical stack view will give that arranged subview the Hugging priority and it will allow the 2nd (Bottom) stack view to stretch vertically.
It is up to you (the designer) to tell auto-layout how much Content Hugging (and Compression Resistance) each view should have.

Thanks @DonMag , Is there any official explanation about the mechanism StackView used to "determine to 1st (Top) stack view to stretch" when the second label is added to one stackview ?

@ximmyxiao - unlikely you'll find an "official explanation" ... when the defined layout is incomplete - or there are conflicts - the behavior is undefined (I'm sure that's mentioned somewhere in the auto-layout docs). Note this is not specific to UIStackView. From a logical standpoint, your layout doesn't really make sense. If the images you've shown reflect how you want the UI to look, then the vertical stack view is unnecessary... and just serves to complicate the layout.

@ximmyxiao - on the other hand, if your images do NOT show what you want, then add some images showing what you're actually trying to do, and show what's not correct based on that layout.

And why change  Vertical Content Hugging Priority on label ,doesnt solve the ambiguous ? I think different Vertical Content Hugging Priority can make the system to determine which label to shrink or expand?

In fact , I was just wondering why this ambiguous is disappeared when you added one more label to the bottom stack . if there is no official guide in this determination who-to-stretch mechanism , the whole procedure is based on your assumption ?@DonMag

@ximmyxiao - I don't work for Apple, so I don't have the auto-layout source code... my comments are based on Logic and Observation. Your layout - as-is - has not provided enough information to inform auto-layout what to do. Adding another label to either Horizontal stack view just happens to give each the priority. Note that if you have 2 labels in the Bottom stack view, and 3 labels in the Top, the layout does not behave the same as 1 and 2 labels.

@ximmyxiao - changing Hugging Priority on a label does not "fix" the issue, because your Horizontal Stack Views have Alignment: Top. Again, if you can tell us what your actual layout goal is, we can probably (almost certainly) help you setup your layout properly.

Thank you so much for your patiently explanation , In fact , I am met an ambiguous just exactly as this :  a V-Stack contains two top-aligned HStack which contain labels . And this ambiguous layout is make me confusing. because in the official doc say a HStack will get it's size from it's largest intrinsicContent size 'child . So because the label 's hugging priority is different. It's easy to decide one HStack keep the size with it's label , and stretch another HStack. the ambiguous should not exist

In fact I found that only two label VS one label will make the difference . If you put two label VS three label . there will be no difference. the ambiguous will not fix

maybe I need to know the whole layout mechanism of UIStackView when its arrangeSubView 's intrinsicContentsize is not defined

@ximmyxiao - you've come across one of many bugs in Xcode's Storyboard / Interface Builder. The "bad layout" Red Icon is not always accurate. Take a look at this video capture: https://i.imgur.com/o1f7Rhu.mp4 ... I have your layout setup, and it shows the Red Icon ... I switch to a different Storyboard and then switch back ... The Red Icon is no longer there! ... I change the background color of the top horizontal stack view ... and the Red Icon is back!!!!

@ximmyxiao - as I've pointed out, you have designed an invalid layout. I cannot tell, based on your Storyboard, how you want the UI elements to behave. Nor have you described what you want (or expect) to happen. Whether or not Xcode accurately alerts you to it is kind of beside the point.

@ximmyxiao - has that explained the issue? Or do you still have questions about it?

,No, In fact, I am  still confusing  why this ambiguous is happen with one-label , and ambiguous disappear with one-two labels .  I will put a more specific question about this ~
